# The relation of pull down list is always one to one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is User table which has sex_id as column and Sex table which has name as column.

In Sex table, there are man and woman records.

User selects man or woman from drop down list.

Above relation is one to many or one to one?

My boss says drop down list is always one to one.

I can't figure out that.

Please teach me?

Comment: how many ids can you have in the sex_id column for a single user ? one.  It is a one-to-one relationship. the user belongs_to a single sex.

Comment: What do you even mean by "drop down list"? If you mean a normal HTML [`<select>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) it can have multiple values if you set the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: But that really has very little to do with assocations or your database schema. It is after all you the programmer who decides what elements to use in the view and how you deal with user input.